# not able to update my database table

Tags: android, database, sql-update

i need to update my password table if the user wants to change password...
how do i do that..
i tried doin it myself but the app is unexpectedly stopped..

here is **changepassword.java**

```
public void insertvalues()
{
    prefEditor.putString("Oldpin", Oldpin);
    prefEditor.putString("Newpin", Newpin);
    prefEditor.putString("Confirm", Confirm);


    prefEditor.commit();

    try
    {

        WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(getApplicationContext());


        way.updatePin(Newpin,Oldpin);



    }
```

and here is **updatePin** function

```
public void updatePin(String newpin,String oldpin)
{
    openOrCreateDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE"+pinTable+"set Pin="+newpin+"where Pin="+oldpin+");");

    closeDatabase();
}
```

what m i doin wrong here?? Pls explain..i cant seem to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your code below seems to lack spaces

```
public void updatePin(String newpin,String oldpin)
{
   openOrCreateDatabase();
   db.execSQL("UPDATE"+pinTable+"set Pin="+newpin+"where Pin="+oldpin+");");

   closeDatabase();
}
```

Would it be better if you have like this?

```
public void updatePin(String newpin,String oldpin)
{
   openOrCreateDatabase();
   db.execSQL("UPDATE "+pinTable+" SET Pin='"+newpin+"' where Pin='"+oldpin+"'");

   closeDatabase();
}
```

If you observe also aside from the spaces that I added, I also added single quote
if it happens that your Pin field/column in your database is of String or Text data type.
Otherwise if it is a numeric say an integer then just remove again the single quote like
the one below.

```
public void updatePin(String newpin,String oldpin)
{
   openOrCreateDatabase();
   db.execSQL("UPDATE "+pinTable+" SET Pin= "+newpin+" where Pin="+oldpin);

   closeDatabase();

}
```

Additionally, I don't know if it is a mistype from your side. But do you need to add ");"
after oldpin+ ?
By the way it is recommendable to separate the sql string in a separate variable. In that way you could easily debug the string itself for any error, like the one below.

```
public void updatePin(String newpin,String oldpin)
{
   String sql = "UPDATE "+pinTable+" SET Pin= "+newpin+" where Pin="+oldpin;
   openOrCreateDatabase();
   db.execSQL(sql);

   closeDatabase();

}
```